# Nativescript and FontAwesome

Tags: android, ios, font-awesome, nativescript

I am trying to use icon font FontAwesome in Nativescript application, which is possible according to this article https://www.nativescript.org/blog/mobile-app-best-practices---use-font-instead-of-image-to-show-an-icon

I did everything that is described in that article:

- Added .ttf in app/fonts
- Added class in app.css

  .fa{
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
  }
- Used it in XML like so

  text="&#xf230;" class="fa"

But result is rather disappointing:

[image: Not working]
I also tried the "\uf230" syntax, but that renders as plain text.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could be a few things. Does it work on iOS? As your CSS definition is iOS compatible, not Android as Android needs the actual filename (without extension) whereas iOS needs the font name. So I have this to be xplatform-ready (the file is 'fontawesome-webfont.ttf'):

```
.fa {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', fontawesome-webfont;
}
```

The `\f005` syntax is OK (`<Label class="fa" [text]="'\uf005'"></Label>`), but I'm using the splendid `nativescript-ngx-fonticon` plugin (there's also a non-Angular one) to be able to do this instead:

`<Label class="fa" [text]="'fa-shopping-basket' | fonticon"></Label>`

Comment: Thanks, adding filename worked on android, since I was testing on android. But will the same declaration work on iOS too? Or do I have to make version for iOS as well?

Comment: See the CSS declaration and the text above it. So yes, this CSS declaration is ready for iOS as well.

Comment: @EddyVerbruggen did you got this working with Font Awesome 5.x?

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, you must make sure that the "fonts" directory is inside the "app" folder and that the following files exist:

```
font-awesome.eot
font-awesome.ttf
```

I opted to adopt this font as the default of my application, so I do not have to worry about where I'm going to use it and how much to enter the right class, everything is getting very good and the result is perfect.

In CSS, you only have to define a selector according to your interest for the source to be used, so just use the directive:

```
page {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome'
}
```

Then where you want an icon, just use an html entity that represents it as it searches the site: http://fontawesome.io/icons/

See images:
[image]

You can see this video where I was based to start. It corrects in the video the extension used to be attentive.

Comment: Thanks. Although, it seems .oet is not really necessary, since it works without it. What is the purpose of it anyway?

Comment: I kept eot per indication, but I understand that only ttf is important in this process.

As you can see from my installation I left all the files for ease.

But if it only works with ttf, the packet gets smaller.