# Nativescript using custom icons on NavigationButton

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to add a button with custom fonts on the ActionBar on a NativeScript Angular app. This is what I tried so far:

```
<ActionBar class="cp-icon">
    <NavigationButton text="&#xE801;" (tap)="goBack()"></NavigationButton>
    <Image src="res://logo_h_white"></Image>
</ActionBar>

// Or one of these optio
<ActionItem text="&#xE801;" (tap)="goBack()"></ActionItem>
<Label text="&#xE801;"></Label>
<Button text="&#xE801;"></Button>
```

But none of them seems to be working. I do have the font instaled because I can use in the view. Also, if I just change the text attribute to be a string instead of an icon, it also doesn't show nothing.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is using the nativescript-ngx-fonticon plugin: https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-ngx-fonticon

Avoid a few common pitfals by also checking this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41861624/2596974

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to mix these. At least the firs link make it easier to apply font icons

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to use `icon.decode="font://&#xE801;"` with a class of your icon font. see below;

```
<NavigationButton text="Wont Show" icon.decode="font://&#xE801;" class="fas" (tap)="goBack()"/>
```

Comment: @celsomtrindade