# How to use custom icon fonts?

Tags: css, fonts, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm creating a cross-platform application with **Nativescript and Angular**.
I had a custom font icon that I want to use. I had some `svg` files that I turned into a `ttf` file. When I use the chars with their unicode code it shows nothing.

What I've done is this:

1. Put the `ttf file` on /src/fonts/icomoon.ttf (the same level of app)
2. Insert this code on `app.css` file

```css
.ico {
    font-family: icomoon, icomoon;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

In the home.component.html file I'm using it like this:

```
<!-- other stuff -->
<Label row="0" col="1" text="&#E904;" class="ico" style="color:white; margin-right:20;" (tap)="showAlert()" />
```

Where am I wrong? Did I miss something?

P.S.: the unicode codes go from e900 to e907

P.P.S: I've already used Fontawesome and it works with this code. Now I want to use my own font and this code doesn't work.

**EDIT**

I use [this guide](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-ngx-fonticon) and I modified something.

In `home.component.html` file I have:

```
<Label row="0" col="1" [text]="'ico-link' | fonticon" class="ico" style="color:white; margin-right:20;" (tap)="showAlert()" />
```

I addedd the file `app/assets/icomoon.css` in which I put this:

```css
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src: url('../../fonts/icomoon');
  src: url('../../fonts/icomoon') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../../fonts/icomoon') format('woff2'), url('../../fonts/icomoon') format('woff'), url('../../fonts/icomoon') format('truetype'), url('../../fonts/icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.ico {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 icomoon;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.ico-link:before {
  content: "\ue904";
}
```

and in `app.ts` I added:

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
       //...
       TNSFontIconModule.forRoot({
                'ico': './assets/icomoon.css'
            })
     ]
    //...
   });
```

After all this it still doesn't work. The icon isn't show.

Comment: Have you tried this? [How to import a new font into a project - Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878988/how-to-import-a-new-font-into-a-project-angular-5)

Comment: Do you have `src` folder at root level? If yes, you are suppose to place the fonts inside root (src) folder. Also make sure you are using the postscript name of the font, it's mandatory use the postscript name on iOS.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong. I have the fonts folder under `src`, at the same level of `app`. I edit the question

Comment: @WojciechX No, I don't know if I can use that. It seems that is another type of project

Comment: @Manoj the name of the file and the postscript name are the same `icomoon`

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue with Playground?

Comment: @Manoj I don't think its's exactly the same because the fonts folder isn't at the same level of the app folder, but it is what I've done. I think the playgroud gives some errors but I haven't much time to resolve. Here is the [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=umrWOB&v=2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nativescript using custom icons on NavigationButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360804/nativescript-using-custom-icons-on-navigationbutton)

Comment: @Narendra in that issue they're using Fontawesome. I want to use my personal icon font.

Comment: Concept is same.

Comment: @Narendra I edited the question, maybe you can understand better.

Comment: I edit again the question with what I tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated your playground [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=umrWOB&v=3). It is working fine now.

In your html I am binding text like this. 
 `<Label textWrap="true" text="{{iconmoonLbl}}" class="ico"></Label>`

and in the .ts file I am using String.fromCharcode
 `this.iconmoonLbl = String.fromCharCode(0xe904);//'&#E904;'`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I needed this solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I notice that it is required to use the whole format `&#xe924;`, then I moved to that awesome icon plugin.

Try

```
<Label row="0" col="1" text="&#xe924;" class="ico" style="color:white; margin-right:20;" (tap)="showAlert()" />
```

Also, remember that Android and IOs handle naming different, please check with using the new docs.

> Note: In iOS your font file should be named exactly as the font name. If you have any doubts about the original font name, use the Font Book app to get the original font name.

[Icon Fonts Nativescript/Angular](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/icon-fonts)