# NativeScript + Angular: How to install and use icons?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I'm trying to use icons on my **nativescript** + **angular** app both for iOS and Android.
I tried different way to set up icons, I used this [tutorial](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/mobile-app-best-practices---use-font-instead-of-image-to-show-an-icon), this [solution](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-fonticon) and I even tried with [material plugin](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-material-icons) and [nativescript-ngx-fonticon](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-ngx-fonticon).

All these methods give me this **error**:

> Plugin nativescript-fontawesome is not included in preview app on
> device [device-id] and will not work.

Now, this is my current code:

***mycomponent.component.html***

`<Button text="&#xf810" class="fa" column="0"></Button>`

***app.css***

```
.fa {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome', fontawesome-webfont;
 }
```

Moreover I have in my ***app/fonts*** folder the following file :

`fontawesome-webfont.ttf`

So, what's wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I think you're getting confused between material icons and awesome font icons

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861386/nativescript-and-fontawesome/41861624

Comment: @alexander.sivak I have already followed the link you sent me, it doesn't work

Comment: @Fmerco No, I'm not confused.. I tried both solutions with FontAwesome and Material Icons... same issue

Comment: @Silvia You presented an example inconsistent with the error

Comment: @Fmerco I corrected it

Comment: try to remove Plugin "nativescript-fontawesome" and change text="&#xf810" to text="&#xf810;"

Comment: @Yong done. I get the same error message: _Plugin nativescript-fontawesome is not included in preview app on device [my-device-id] and will not work_

Comment: You can not use all the plugins with preview app, it allows only limited number of plugins those were packed with the app (such as camera, image picker etc.,) To use Font Awesome icon on buttons / images like showcased above, you do not need a plugin. The code should work as long as you have a right icon set and font file installed. If you still have issues, please share a Playground sample.

Comment: @Silvia, You do not need a plugin. I share a demo, https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=IP5pOk&v=3. You can also provide a sample, so that we can help you further.

Answer (score 6):

There's no need for a plugin anymore. NativeScript supports Icon Fonts.
https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/icon-fonts

- Download the FontAwesome fonts for the web at https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself from the "Download Font Awesome Free for the Web" box.
- Save the *.ttf files in `src/fonts`:

  - fa-regular-400.ttf
  - fa-brands-400.ttf
  - fa-solid-900.ttf
- Add these lines to your app.css

```
.far {
    font-family: Font Awesome 5 Free, fa-regular-400;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.fab {
    font-family: Font Awesome 5 Brands, fa-brands-400;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.fas {
    font-family: Font Awesome 5 Free, fa-solid-900;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

- You can now use

```
<!-- Using fa-solid-900.ttf -->
<Button text="&#xf810;" class="fas"></Button>
```